# Split and Append a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows:

```
['aaa > bbb', 'ccc > ddd', 'eee >  ']
```

I am looking to split the list to get the following result, with an empty string element at the end

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee','']
```

I tried the following code

```
for element in list:
    list.append(element.split(' > '))
```

I am getting answer as follows:

```
[['aaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc', 'ddd'], ['eee','']]
```

After thinking I see that is what it supposed to work as. So how can I achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: Is appending to the same list you're iterating on intended? That said, you want to replace append with extend.

Comment: Please, don't use `list` as a variable: it's a built-in function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
l = ['aaa > bbb', 'ccc > ddd', 'eee >  ']
[item.strip() for sublist in [element.split(">") for element in l] for item in sublist]
```

The output is:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', '']
```

I admit that this list comprehension is not super easy and understandable but it's a one-liner :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for element in list:
    list.extend(element.split(' > '))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
list.extend(iterable)

    Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```py
a = ['aaa > bbb', 'ccc > ddd', 'eee >  ']
newlist = []

for element in a:
    newlist += element.split(' > ')
```

Append method just adds the argument as a new element, the simple addition solves your problem.